# Why Govardhan Hill is considered a form of Krishna?

Tags: krishna

Followers of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu worship Krishna in a small stone form (Govardhana sila) representing Mount Govardhan. The question  is Why Govardhan Hill is considered a form of Krishna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Govardhana hill is considered a form of Krishna because Shri Krishna had declared it Himself:

> *kṛṣṇas tv anyatamaṁ rūpaṁ gopa-viśrambhaṇaṁ gataḥ
>
>   śailo ’smīti bruvan bhūribalim ādad bṛhad-vapuḥ*  [SB - 10.24.35]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Kṛṣṇa then assumed an unprecedented, huge form to instill faith in the cowherd men. Declaring “**I am Govardhana Mountain**!” He ate the abundant offerings.

And because Shri Krishna had told it Himself, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu also respected and directed to worship Govardhan Sila:

> *prabhu kahe, — “ei śilā kṛṣṇera vigraha
>
>   iṅhāra sevā kara tumi kariyā āgraha* [CC - 3.6.294]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu says, “This stone is the form of Lord Shri Krishna. You worship this with great eagerness.”

Answer (score 0):

It is said the Lord Krishna carried Govardhana Hill and saved Vrindavan from the wrath of Indra deva.  Govardhana Hill was very dear to Shri Krishna - he justified it in the Bhagavatam when he said that (they) should worship Govardhana because it gives grass to the cows, land and shelter to live, everything that the village used was more likely dependent upon Govardhana.  Govardhana Hill was dear to Krishna, therefore it became of form of Krishna or divine love.

The truth is, why only Govardhana Hill?  Not only Govardhana Hill but any place (even your own heart), can be dear to Krishna.  And anything that is dear to Krishna, can be considered a form of Krishna.  This is because Krishna resides in the hearts of his dear ones.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.